# In h5 page I want to open app(had schema already) when the iPhone install the app if not jump to appstore

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html

As I said in title,I used the following JS Code:

```
<a href="https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/id1111" id="openApp" style="display: none">openApp</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('openApp').onclick = function(e){

    window.location.href = "haocai://";
    window.setTimeout(function(){
         window.location.href = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id11113?mt=8";
    },3000)
};
```

This code has a problem, if the iPhone has no the app, the Safari will popup a problem, so can the problem be solved?

Comment: What is the `popup problem`?

Comment: if the phone has no the app, the Safair will popoup a confirm box,tell the user can't open the url.This is a bad user experience